# iron-router restrict admin access with hooks

Tags: meteor, iron-router

i have a problem with iron-router.

when I first load the page /admin/deps, then route will work out fine. Then I go to any other page by clicking on the link, and then back to /admin/deps/ in that time in the console I get "Route dispatch never rendered. Did you forget to call this.next() in an onBeforeAction?" and template is not rendering

BUT .. if I change anything in the code using hot-swap code, a meteor reloads the page and in this case, everything works as expected.

here are my controllers and routes:

```
class @AdminRouteController extends RouteController
  onBeforeAction: ->
    console.log "onBeforeAction: #{@url}"
    if Meteor.loggingIn()
      @render 'loading'
    else if !Meteor.userId() or !Meteor.user().hasAccess 'admin'
      @render 'notFound'
    else
      @next()

class @AdminPagebleRouteController extends AdminRouteController
  pageable: true 
  perPage: 20    

  limit: (name = null) ->
    Session.get(varName(@, name)) || @perPage

  incLimit: (name = null, inc = null) ->
    inc ||= @perPage
    Session.set varName(@, name), (@limit(name) + inc)

  resetLimit: (name = null) ->
    Session.set varName(@, name), null

  loaded: (name = null) ->
    true

  onRerun: ->
    console.log "onRerun: #{@url}"
    @next()

Router.route '/admin', name: 'admin'
class @AdminController extends AdminRouteController
  template: 'adminHome'
  action: ->
    document.title = i18n 'admin.title'
    super()

Router.route '/admin/deps', name: 'deps'
class @DepsController extends AdminPagebleRouteController
  template: 'deps'
  perPage: 20

  waitOn: ->
    @subscribe 'adminDeps', @limit()

  data: ->
    deps: DepartmentsCollection.find()

  loaded: ->
    @limit() > DepartmentsCollection.find().count()

  action: ->
    document.title = i18n 'deps.title'
    super()

  onRun: ->
    console.log "onRun: #{@url}"
    @resetLimit()
    @next()

  load: ->
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 400)
    $('.content').hide().fadeIn(1000)
```

and here is console screen when route does not work properly
[image]

Here is code in javascript:

```
AdminRouteController = RouteController.extend({
  onBeforeAction: function(){
    console.log("onBeforeAction: " + this.url);
    if(Meteor.loggingIn())
      this.render('loading');
    else if(!Meteor.userId() || !Meteor.user().hasAccess('admin'))
      this.render('notFound');
    else
      this.next();
  }
});

varName = function(inst, name){
  name = name && ("_" + name || "");
  return inst.constructor.name + name + "_limit";
}

AdminPagebleRouteController = AdminRouteController.extend({
  pageable: true,
  perPage: 20,

  limit: function (name){
    return Session.get(varName(this, name)) || this.perPage;
  },
  incLimit: function (name, inc){
    inc = inc ? inc : this.perPage;
    return Session.set(varName(this, name), (this.limit(name) + inc));
  },
  resetLimit: function (name){
    return Session.set(varName(this, name), null);
  },
  loaded: function (name){
    return true;
  },
  onRerun: function (){
    console.log("onRerun: " + this.url);
    this.next();
  }
});

Router.route('/admin', name: 'admin');
AdminController = AdminRouteController.extend({
  template: 'adminHome',
  action: function(){
    document.title = i18n('admin.title');
    super();
  }
});

Router.route('/admin/deps', name: 'deps');
DepsController = AdminPagebleRouteController.extend({
  template: 'deps',
  perPage: 20,

  waitOn: function(){
    this.subscribe('adminDeps', this.limit());
  },
  data: function(){
    return { deps: DepartmentsCollection.find() };
  },
  loaded: function(){
    return this.limit() > DepartmentsCollection.find().count();
  },
  action: function(){
    document.title = i18n('deps.title');
    super();
  },
  onRun: function(){
    console.log("onRun: " + this.url);
    this.resetLimit();
    this.next();
  },
  load: function(){
    $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, 400);
    $('.content').hide().fadeIn(1000);
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I've found the answer, problem was in DepsController, in `load()` function. It fired before `onBeforeAction()`, and it is also need to call `this.next ()`

Answer (score 0):

Can you put your code in a classic Javascript syntax? Almost all docs are not in the language you provide, which does not ease the support you could get.

Besides, I would say your onBeforeAction of your class @AdminRouteController might be buggy. Try to slice your if/elseif/else statement in multiple if like this:

```
class @AdminRouteController extends RouteController
  onBeforeAction: ->
    console.log "onBeforeAction: #{@url}"
    if Meteor.loggingIn()
      @render 'loading'
    else 
      @next()

    if !Meteor.userId() or !Meteor.user().hasAccess 'admin'
      @render 'notFound'
    else
      @next()
```

Hope this helps, but I would be more helpful with a classic javascript syntax tbh.

## EDIT

Thx for putting your code in .js.
Usually, when you got the error "Route dispatch never rendered. Did you forget to call this.next() in an onBeforeAction?" it's because you forget to call this.next() in an onBeforeAction() or onRun() somewhere. Need to figure out where...

Cheers,

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I was added code in js. On your recommendation is an error, because in the same hook-funcrion called twice this.next()

Comment: Without my recommendation, do you have the same problem with your /admin route?

Comment: No, other routes works fine. I tried change waitOn on subscriptions, but got the same result

Comment: is this.next() necessary in action? Also, you should consider to reorder the logic of your hooks which are messy imo. Are you using iron:router 1.0?

Comment: I think is necessary in action. I dont know how else render specific template for a not-admin users. I use latest version of iron router 1.0.3